# Selected Spinner Item as String for a new Cursor

Tags: android, string, cursor, spinner, simplecursoradapter

Right now I am almost done writing my app. All I need is a bit help on getting the selected String value from a spinner populated from my database by a simple cursor adapter. I am not sure how I can get the String from my spinner and pass it to a different cursor and use the string in a query, that will populate depending on the first choice of the spinner, and so on with other spinners.

Here is the code I am using for one of my spinners.

```
vType = (Cursor) DataBaseHelper.getPowersportsType();
    this.startManagingCursor(vType);

        SimpleCursorAdapter scaType = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                vType,
                new String [] {DataBaseHelper.POWERSPORTS_TYPE},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

        scaType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        vTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.typeSpinner);
        vTypeSpinner.setAdapter(scaType);
```

And this is my query for the next spinner in my xml layout

```
static String MakeWhere = "POWERSPORTS_TYPE=?";
public static Cursor getPowersportsMake(){
return myDataBase.query(POWERSPORTS_TABLE, 
    new String [] {POWERSPORTS_ID, POWERSPORTS_MAKE}, 
    MakeWhere, 
    null, 
    POWERSPORTS_MAKE, 
    null, 
    null);
}
```

Any comments or suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the item selected you need to set the `onItemSelectedListener`

then in your onItemtSelected all you would do is

```
String selection = vTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: So how would I use the String that is selected in the Spinner as a variable in my queries?